# What is the chord played by 1-6-1?

Tags: chord-theory

I am not professional in music, and this may be a dumb question, but I couldn't find an answer for a long time. I observed that in a lot of cases, the chord is played as 1-6-1, and I don't know exactly what is its name. For example, the second chord from the music sheet below is D-B-D:

[image]

Sometimes I thought it is just D major, but sometimes I think it may be different.
Could you help me name that chord, and by the way also the remaining 3 chords in the sheet piece above. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would interpret the chord in the second bar as D6. Maybe you could think of it as Bm/D, but the pedal note D in the bass makes me feel like D is the root. In the melody the notes A and F# complete the chord. C# is major seventh, it's essentially a chord tone too.

So the whole progression in the four measures would be:

- Dmaj9 (F# is not played, so at the very first occurrence it may sound ambiguous)
- D6 (maj7 if you want to be strict)
- Dmaj7 (again, F# is not played, but we heard it in the previous measure)
- D6 (no F# again)

This is a very soft progression. The root of all these chords is the same (D). The third is played only once, in the melody, so while it is present in the harmony, it gives a very open sound of the fifth (or sixth) between the bass note and the note above it. A downward movement: E-D-C#-B emphasizes different colors (upper structures) of the same chord rather than provides a strong harmonic motion.

Comment: For the chord at the second bar, could it be Dmaj13, as that bar has these notes D-(F#)-A-C#-B?

Comment: @HieuNguyen The convention is that "13" is typically used only for dominant chords. Otherwise symbols like D6, Dmaj7, D6/9 often represent the same harmony, with some suggestion which tones to emphasize. Chord symbols don't specify every single note in the chord, but rather provide a generalization of the harmony. If you want to write exactly what notes are to be played, write the notes on the staff.

Comment: Alternately, instead of D6 one could view it as a Bm in first inversion. There's a lot of ways to look at it, but the gist is D in the bass along with some sort of relative-minor-y flavour. +1

Comment: @user45266 right, B minor, not B as I wrote previously, my mistake

Comment: I think @user45266 hits the nail on the head. My analysis teacher had this rule that "your analysis must not be clearer than the piece itself". The progression is deliberately vague in feel, among others by leaving out the thirds in most chords. So it's not surprising that you cannot easily make out what the chords or their functions are, or at least not with any kind of decisiveness.